# PHPUnit Database - no such table

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to run very simple PHPUnit testing class with Database simulation. I am trying to create dataset with some values. I am using MySQL XML object.

My MySQL XML Object is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <database name="some_test_db">
        <table_data name="some_test_table">
        <row>
            <field name="id">1</field>
            <field name="content_time">1382774967</field>
            <field name="ip">10.0.0.10</field>
            <field name="content">test message</field>
        </row>
        </table_data>
    </database>
    </mysqldump>
```

My PHP code in the testing class is:

```
<?php 

class TestOfDatabase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    }   
      protected function setUp() {
        $this->getConnection()->createDataSet();
    }

     /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite');
    }

    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
     */
    public function getDataSet() {
        return $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/dataset.xml');
    }

    public function testGetInstance() {
      $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('some_test_table'));
    }
}
```

When I am running TestofDatabase I get "General error 1: no such table: some_test_table".

I can't understand why the mock DB is not being populated with the data that I inserted to dataset.xml.

I already checked that the path is OK.

Comment: Have you selected the database first?

Comment: No, Should I do it? When to do it? In the setup? or in the test function?

Comment: You could try getRowCount('some_test_db.some_test_table')

Comment: Tried it. but it doesn't work... :-(

Comment: Sorry, I knew it was a shot in the dark but thought it might be worth exploring.

Comment: According to the docs, it seems the database name is provided as the second parameter of `createDefaultDBConnection` (`$this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, $database);`)

Comment: I know, I tried the following alternatives:
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'memory');
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite::memory');
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite::memory:');
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'some_test_db');

Nothing worked.

Comment: What about: `protected function getConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=some_test_db', 'root', '');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'some_test_db');
    }`

Comment: I want to use the sqlite:memory DB and not MySQL based DB.

Comment: The manual suggests that should be set up like : `$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, ':memory:');`. Is the database name in the XML optional? Might be worth simplifying your dataset if possible too.

Comment: Done it - also tried to remove the database name attribute and even moved to Flat Xml DataSet and it still not working. very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an XML file generated by MySQL's utility program.  This can probably only be reloaded into a MySQL database.  Since you are using SQLite for your testing, try using the simpler XML style as your data source: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html#database.xml-dataset

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<dataset>
    <table name="some_test_table">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>content_time</column>
        <column>ip</column>
        <column>content</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>1382774967</value>
            <value>10.0.0.10</value>
            <value>test message</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```